# function scope javascript, returning outside of function

Tags: javascript, redis

I have this function in JS:

```
 function redGet(key){
    var response;
    red.get(key, function (err, reply) {
            response = reply;
        });
    return response;
    }
```

This keeps returning undefined on :

```
console.log(redGet("hello"));
```

Comment: Can you explain what `red` is?

Comment: What's `redis.createClient()`? Are you sure that the `red.get()` function is working in the first place?

Comment: ya it is...putting console.log inside that function returns "world"

Comment: @Blender it's probably an async call. I see no guarantee that the anonymous function setting the value of "response" will execute before the return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `red.get()` is an AJAX-like asynchronous function, the problem is that you're expecting it to operate synchronously. You won't be able to get the `reply` value until the asynchronous operation is complete, which means that anything that relies on this value must be invoked in the callback function.

For example:

```
function redGet(key){
    red.get(key, function (err, reply) {
        // do whatever you need to do with the reply value here
        console.log(reply);
    });
}

redGet("hello");
```

Comment: See my edit for an example. In practice, with your current code, you're not getting much out of the `redGet()` function that's not provided by `red.get()`, though you might use it for consistent error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what `red` is, but most likely its `.get()` method is *asynchronous*, which means execution of `redGet()` continues immediately with `return response` at which point the value *is* undefined. It is only later after `.get()` finishes its processing that your callback function is executed to set `response - reply`.

As with any asynchronous code (also found in Ajax, database access, etc. code) you will likely need to restructure your code such that whatever depends on the return value from `.get()` is executed in your callback function (or in other functions called from the callback).

Comment: Yeah. Can't we just mark this as a duplicate of one of the other billions of "how do I return a value from this async call" questions?

Comment: @GGG - well, it's sort of a duplicate, but every unhappy asynchronous method is unhappy in its own way, if you see what I mean. What would be nice is if there was a single SO reference page so that we didn't need to write this explanation a billion times.

Comment: I think that's called Google ;) But the main problem is people not knowing what to search. It'd be nice if SO's duplicate question logic was a bit smarter.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your `red.get` is an ajax function call (which is asynchronous)

What happen is your `console.log(..)` get executed before `red.get(..)` get the result back.

If you still want it to work you have to pass a callback to it e.g.

```
redGet('hello', function(res) {
    alert(res)
})

// then in your code 
function redGet(key, cb){
    red.get(key, function (err, reply) {
        cb(reply)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery $.ajax function with async:false option. May be red variable uses jquery $.ajax function inside and you can do this. But it will affect the performance.
More information on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/